# Remove namedtuple from list based on value

Tags: python, list, namedtuple

Consider the following class that extends a `list` and appends `orderedtuple`s:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Order = namedtuple('Order', ['id', 'value'])


class Orders(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(Orders, self).__init__()
        self.extend(args)

    def add(self, id, value):
        self.append(Order(id, value))
```

...add some elements...

```
order = Orders()

order.add(1, 'alpha')
order.add(2, 'beta')
order.add(3, 'lambda')
order.add(4, 'omega')
```

...and we're left with...

```
print order
[Order(id=1, value='alpha'), Order(id=2, value='beta'), Order(id=3, value='lambda'), Order(id=4, value='omega')]
```

Say I want to remove an arbitrary element by it's `id`. For example:

```
order.remove(id=2) # ideal function call to remove by `id`
print order
[Order(id=1, value='alpha'), Order(id=3, value='lambda'), Order(id=4, value='omega')]
```

Is there a reasonably simple method to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it the slow way:

```
def remove(self, id=None, value=None):
    for elem in self:
        if (id is not None and elem.id == id or
                value is not None and elem.value == value):
            super(Orders, self).remove(elem)
            break
```

You could add an index to your class that tracks maps ids and / or values to specific indices, but you'd need to keep that index up-to-date as you manipulate the contained list of orders. It'd look something like this:

```
def __init__(self, *args):
    # ...
    self._ids = {}

def append(self, id, value):
    if id in ids:
        raise ValueError('This order already exists!')
    super(Orders, self).append(Order(id, value))
    self._ids[id] = len(self) - 1
```

and, provided you also adjust all other methods that can alter the list and change ordering, etc., you can then find orders quickly by their id:

```
def remove(self, id):
    if id not in self._ids
        raise ValueError('No such order exists!')
    del self[self._ids[id]]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
[namedtuple for namedtuple in list if namedtuple.id != 'id']
```

Comment: In the future, post code by selecting it and clicking the `{}` widget, so it renders correctly.  Someone else did it for you this time.

Comment: Thank you @JeffLearman

Answer (score 1):

You can build a custom `remove` method to do this for you:

```
def remove(self, id):
    for index, item in enumerate(self):
        if item.id == id:
            break
    else:
        raise ValueError("id not found")

    del self[index]
```

Demo:

```
>>> class Orders(list):
...     def __init__(self, *args):
...         super(Orders, self).__init__()
...         self.extend(args)
...     def add(self, id, value):
...         self.append(Order(id, value))
...     def remove(self, id):
...         for index, item in enumerate(self):
...             if item.id == id:
...                 break
...         else:
...             raise ValueError("id not found")
...         del self[index]
...
>>> order = Orders()
>>> order.add(1, 'alpha')
>>> order.add(2, 'beta')
>>> order.add(3, 'lambda')
>>> order.add(4, 'omega')
>>> order
[Order(id=1, value='alpha'), Order(id=2, value='beta'), Order(id=3, value='lambda'), Order(id=4, value='omega')]
>>> order.remove(2)
>>> order
[Order(id=1, value='alpha'), Order(id=3, value='lambda'), Order(id=4, value='omega')]
>>> order.remove(5)  # Nonexistent id
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 12, in remove
ValueError: id not found
>>>
```

Note that the function only makes one pass over the data, just like the normal `list.remove`.

The main advantage of this solution is simplicity.  You can implement the `remove` method without changing any other parts of the class definition.  That said, it still runs in `O(n)` complexity.  If performance is your main concern, then you should take the time to implement the `O(1)` id-lookup approach proposed by @MartijnPieters.

Comment: These will be relatively small lists so in this case performance is not a major concern.